# Compare two raster matrices to find similar patterns (not specific values!) - R/Python

Tags: python, r, matrix, pattern-matching, spatial

I am trying to find a method to identify similar patterns in two matrices. I don't want to check if the entire matrix A correlates with matrix B but rather if they have the same pattern e.g., if high values in the upper right corner of A causes high values in the upper right corner of B.

Context: I want to check if there is influx of microbial activity between two layers of soil.

Does anyone have an idea on how to approach this?

I use R and Python so I'm not bound to one program.

[image]

[image]

Example code for R:

```
type <- rep(c("A","B"),each=24)
cell <- rep(c("1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10","11","12","13","14","15","16","17","18","19","20","21","22","23","24"),times=2)
colv <- rep(c("1","2","3","4","5","6"),times=8)
rowv <- rep(c("A","B","C","D","A","B","C","D"),each=6)
value <- c(3.320778259,3.226212426,3.216976903,3.275288183,3.196077221,3.241266188,3.103958442,3.265778521,3.276232876,3.245281036,3.325703943,3.243101829,3.177311733,3.152218722,3.227082725,3.266158007,3.285040043,3.215106616,3.201382141,3.174154668,3.211670345,3.207109622,3.292156445,3.19718622,1.893001625,1.924067381,1.955004633,1.877662104,1.907755972,1.905813059,1.913575199,1.899521528,1.924332598,1.900693991,1.868313952,1.88193412,1.820855727,1.936481397,1.999290805,1.839718217,1.900652919,1.80438663,1.949529493,1.816243452,1.903458919,1.941922998,1.780818789,1.968353414)

df <- data.frame("type" = type, 
             "cell" = cell, 
             "col"=colv, 
             "row"=rowv, 
             "value"=value)
df
```

Comment: how are your low and high values defined? Are they single values or a range of values say for example a range between 0-20 is low or all values lower than 20 are low values.

Comment: Questions that are not focused on a single language or have no code attempt or do not show the input in reproducible form are typically closed.  See top of [tag:r] tag page for info on asking questions.

Comment: Can I edit my post to add code? 

High values are not defined and are specific to the respective matrix e.g., the highest value of each matrix.

Example: 
A = [1,1,2,1,3,44
        1,4,55,1,10]
B = [1,2,1,2,3,20
        0,0,10,0,2]

Comment: @BobSacamano  yes u can do this just click on edit at the  bottom of your question